Can’t type in Sublime Text in full-screen or distraction-free modes
If I enter either full-screen mode or distraction-free mode (via their commands under the menu bar’s View menu, or via their keyboard shortcuts), I can no longer type. All keypresses that don’t include modifier keys result in macOS error noises, until I close and reopen the document.
macOS 14.6.1
Sublime Text 4180
